# Targeting html elements inside div using css

Tags: html, css

Given this HTML as an example, is there a way to target all the elements inside a given `<div>` individually without having to change each CSS selector.

```
<div id="div1">
  <h3>h3 div 1</h3>
  <!-- whole bunch of html here -->
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <h3>div 2</h3>
  <!-- whole bunch of html here -->
</div>
```

This is how I normally do it...

```
#div1 > h3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

However i am looking for a solution like this (treat this as **pseudo code**)

```
#div2 {
  h3 {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/8bstkq7u/1/

Comment: Change css to scss in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8bstkq7u/2/ `:)`

Comment: What you're trying to do looks a bit like nesting in the CSS preprocessor SASS. It's not supported in CSS. Note that to use this in the real world you have to write SASS and compile it to genuine CSS. Browsers can't understand it before it's been compiled.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail? I don't understand from the short description what the real problem is.

Comment: @NenadVracar well that made it simple. what is SCSS? and what does it take to use it? a library?

Comment: I might be wrong but i think scss is main syntax of SASS and SASS is `CSS with superpowers` more here http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Here's playground site so you can see how it works - http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/86488e33ea26472c110d

Comment: You just have to remember that the CSS Pre-processors still **output** CSS. They just make it quicker and easier to *write* CSS in the end.

Comment: Thanks everyone! My mind is blown right now, to think of all the wasted time i have had in the past with issues like this solved so simply.

Comment: be aware that excessive nesting using CSS preprocessors like SASS can cause huge code bloat in the output CSS. Writing raw css will force you to learn better design principles rather than giving you a bunch of shortcuts.

Comment: what you try to do is `#div2 h3 {background-color: lightgreen; }` !?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exactly this syntax if you use scss. Change css to scss in your fiddle and your code will work.

This guide is a good point to start: [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: Thank you! My mind is blown right now, to think of all the wasted time i have had in the past with issues like this solved so simply.